# How to compare open sets from $\mathbb{R}$ with the finite complement topology and the standard topology?

Tags: general-topology

I am being asked about which of the two topologies are finer than the other and I am having troubles once I am not able to say what are a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ with the finite complement topology, so I don't know how to compare such topologies.

Any comments will be very helpful.

Comment: Finite complement: the closed sets are the finite (including empty) and entire space. Each is closed in the standard topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that finite sets are closed if $\mathbb R$ is equipped with the standard topology, so that cofinite sets belong to that topology. That means that the standard topology is *finer* than the finite complement topology.

Also there are sets belonging to the standard topology that are not cofinite. This allows us to conclude that the standard topology is *properly finer* than the finite complement topology.

Comment: Thank you! Another question that remains is, when I have to compare such topologies using the fact that for an element of one basis there is an element of another basis that is contained on the first, for this second element can I choose unions or finite intersections of elementos of the second basis? If I have to show that $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{B}'$ can I choose intersections of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ for being contenaid in $\mathcal{B}'$ or I just have to take necessarily one element? The point of this question is, finite intersections and arbitrary unions of elements of a basis

Comment: still are elements of the basis?

Comment: A basis is *not* necessarily closed under finite intersections and is *not* necessarily closed under unions, if that's what you mean. If you compare topologies $\tau$ and $\tau'$ that have bases $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B'$ respectively then you can check wether elements $B\in\mathcal B$ are open in $\tau'$. For this purpose you can use $\mathcal B'$. Set $B$ is open in $\tau'$ if you can write is a union of elements in $\mathcal B'$. That comes to checking wether for each $b\in B$ you can find an element $B'\in\mathcal B'$ such that $b\in B'\subseteq B$.

Comment: thanks a lot! Now everything is clear.

Comment: You are welcome.